# Agregar elementos a un char[] existente c#

Tags: c#, array, ascii

Tengo la duda y no la puedo resolver, he intentado listas de char[] y tampoco, me explico...

```
char[] entradas;
var input = 'A'..'Z'+'a'..'z';
var texto = input.Split('+');
foreach (var set in texto)
                {
                    var tipo = set.Trim().Split(new string[] { ".." }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                    byte[] start;
                    byte[] end;
                    int rank;
                    start = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tipo[0]);
                    end = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(tipo[1]);
                    var nd = end.Max();
                    rank = nd - start[1] + 1;
                    entradas = Enumerable.Range(start[1], rank).Select(x => (char)x).ToArray();
                }
```

Lo utilizo para conseguir una serie de ASCII dependiendo de la entrada, pero no me deja agregar rangos como en listas, solo me permite sobre escribirlas.
Pueden haber varias interacciones en este ciclo, es por eso que necesito agregar rangos de ASCIIs y no solo ponerlos en la variable.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo solucioné de una forma no tan buena, creo...
Agregué una

> var myList = new list();

y luego de obtener el rango que necesito

> foreach(var item in entradas){
>   myList.add(item.ToString());
>   }